# dynamically find out num of args for while read in bash

Tags: bash, arguments

Let's say in `file1` I have random number of words per line,
Is there a way for `while read` to know for each line how many of them
is supposed to read, here I have hardcoded three:

```
while read w1 w2 w3
do
    # grep [some regex] file2
done <<< $(awk '{print $0}' file1)
```

But wondering if it would be possible to have something like:

```
while read [*words] #as many as they are for the current line I am getting from awk
    ...
    ...
done <<< $(awk '{print $0}' file1)
```

Is that possible, without writing more complex script in a separate file,
but running directly from terminal?

Comment: Why are you using `<<<`, `$(...)` and `awk` when `done < file1` would suffice?

Comment: It was a leftover from previous command, where I needed specific fields only from `file1`. Thanks for noticing though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious way :

```
while read words; do
    for word in $words; do ...; done
done < file1
```

Comment: This assumes `$words` doesn't contain any pattern metacharacters (such as `*` or `?`) which could cause a successful match to one or more files in the current directory.

Comment: no it doesn't contain those metacharacters, if it were containing any how would I protect from file globbing?

Comment: You could disable globbing by running `set -f`, re-enabling it with `set +f` afterwards. I recommend Ignacio's answer, though.

Answer (score 3):

Read them into an array. You can then use normal array techniques after.

```
while read -a words
   ...
done < file1
```

Comment: Did you mean `-A` not `-a`?

Comment: @branquito: No, I didn't.

Comment: I know I said `bash`, but why in `zsh` it says bad option?

Comment: The options supported by `read` in `bash` and `zsh` differ quite a bit. `read -a` is correct for `bash`; `read -A` for `zsh`.